# Integrate another api's return data to service method

Tags: java, spring-boot

Below is my service code for uploading questions into my database; However, I have another api for loading images into these questions from my frontend. 
In order to set that relevant image into the database, i have the code:

```
question.setImage_urls(cloudStorageHelper.getUrl());
```

This is the code for setImage url to the database where used in cloudstoragehelper class. So how should I integrate that piece of code into following code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/saveQuestion")
public ResponseEntity<?> saveQuestion( @RequestBody Question question ) throws IOException, ServletException, InterruptedException, NullPointerException
{           return new ResponseEntity<>( questionService.saveQuestion( question ), HttpStatus.CREATED );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try to create a new data base to save image urls and from creating a service get those image urls to your front end( seems you want to bind data to front end) so from front end bind the value to the image url. will be much more beneficial for you in future. just a suggestion

Comment: just try it. just a suggestion :D